# typescript error is not allowed as a variable declaration name.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using next.js , react, and typescript.
When I use switch as a variable name, I get a typescript error.
How can I avoid the error?

```
'switch' is not allowed as a variable declaration name.ts(1389)
```

```
const Template: Story = (args: AtomSwitchProps) => <Switch {...args} />;

export const switch = Template.bind({});
switch.args = {
};
```

Comment: switch is reserverd word in js. use different name

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear - that name is not allowed, so you have to use a different name.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a keyword as an identifier in your JavaScript programs. Switch is a `Reserved keyword`. Reserved keywords are used to perform internal operations. [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_words) a list of keywords of JavaScript.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Yeah, by changing the name of the variable

Comment: Link is broken, there's a new one: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: For my use-case, I found a trick to use "default" as a string during the return, instead of returning the const:
Original code that returned an error: 
`const default = null; return { default };`
Returning a string directly works: 
`return { "default": null };`